# Efficiently using addEventListener on multiple navigation elements

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using some javascript to listen for mouseenter on a navigation element with an id of `#drop-nav-trigger`. The idea is that if they don't hover over it for more than 250ms then the elements dropdown menu does not activate. I wanted to prevent it from showing if the user is simply moving their mouse over the element to get to somewhere else on the page. It works great!

But now I want to do the same thing for two or more elements in the same navigation menu (but not ALL of the elements). How do I handle this? Do I just duplicate my javascript for each nav item I want to have this functionality? Or is there a way to combine it all into one snippet of code?

Here is an example of my HTML. In this example I'd like the javascript to watch the first two top level elements for mouseenter but ignore the third one. I figured the `has-submenu` will be what I need to watch for.

```
<ul class="main-nav-wrapper">
    <li id="drop-nav-trigger" class="nav-item has-submenu">
        Browse Products
        <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
        Second Top Level Item
        <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        Third Top Level Item
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is my javascript. I'm using some jQuery in there as well to add the `active` class to the nav item. Once the script adds `active` to the element I use CSS to reveal the hidden submenu.

I think my problem is that unlike listening for the ID, my classes are shared among multiple elements. So if I listen to it I'm going to end up adding `active` to all of my matching elements.

```
var timeoutId = null;
var el = document.getElementById("drop-nav-trigger");

/* Activate menu after a delay. */
if(el) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseenter',function() { 
       timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function(){

            $("#drop-nav-trigger").addClass("active");

       }, 250);
     } );

    // Cancel your action if mouse moved out within 2 sec
    el.addEventListener('mouseleave',function() { 
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        $("#drop-nav-trigger").removeClass("active");
    });

}
```

Comment: You seem to be using jQuery to add and remove classes - would you be happy with a jQuery based solution?  (Doing so would probably vastly reduce the amount of code required)

Comment: Absolutely, I have no problem with going full jQuery to solve this problem. I believe if I were able to use $(this) that it would solve my problem. But I don't know enough javascript to know what the equivalent is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) functionality, which accepts two callbacks - one for `mouseenter`, one for `mouseleave`.  We use this on all `.has-submenu` items.  You were worried about adding `.active` to all matching subitems - within the callback functions jQuery passes the actual element as `this`, so we can make use of that to ensure we only add it to the right one:

```
$('.has-submenu').hover(function() {
    //mouseenter callback

    //keep separate reference to this so we can use it in the timeout function
    var li = this;

    $(li).data('timeoutId', setTimeout(function() {
        $(li).addClass('active');
    }, 250));

}, function() {
    //mouseleave callback
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

In addition, I'm using the [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function to store the timer ID on each individual element so they don't interfere with each other, and it also removes the need for the `timeoutId` variable outside of the scope of these functions.